# nullity of infinite matrix A equals nullity of $A^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis

Suppose you have an infinite matrix A with real entries. I know the dimension of the null space of A.

Question 1) if the dimension of the null space is a finite number k, is the dimension of the null space of $A^T$ also k?

Question 2) if the dimension of the null space of A is infinite, is the dimension of the null space of $A^T$ also infinite?

Thanks!

Comment: Can we consider an infinite matrix a square matrix?

Comment: What's the null space of an infinite matrix?

Comment: @user1551 what's wrong with your answer?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom It's too complicated and it doesn't really explain *why* the nullity (or at least the finitude/infinitude of the nullity) is not preserved. So, basically, I didn't like it and I deleted it.

Comment: You need to define exactly what you mean by "null space" for an infinite matrix.  An arbitrary infinite matrix cannot be evaluated on an arbitrary infinite "vector", since you get infinite sums that might not converge.

Comment: @user1551 okay.  It's interesting because I was going to post about the same thing before I had seen that you beat me to it.  If you want a "why" for this context (if you still intend on putting an answer together), I think it suffices to note the failure of the rank-nullity theorem in infinite dimensions.  I believe we still have, however, $im(A^TA) = im(A^T)$ and $\ker(A^TA) = \ker(A)$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Please feel free to post your answer. I don't think I can answer this question well.

Comment: @user1551 I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 3):

I assume for simplicity that we are regarding these infinite matrices as maps from $\ell^2$ to $\ell^2$.

With credit to user1551, here are some examples in which the statement fails:

**Failure of 1:** The shift operators on $\ell^2(\mathbb R)$ (equipped with the inner product $\langle x,y\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_ky_k$) would give you an easy counterexample:
$$
A=\pmatrix{0\\ 1&0\\ &1&\ddots\\ &&\ddots&\ddots},
\ A^T=\pmatrix{0&1\\ &0&1\\ &&\ddots&\ddots\\ &&&\ddots}.
$$
$Ax=0$ has only the trivial solution, but $A^Te_1=0$.

**Failure of 2:** On $\ell^2(\mathbb R)$, consider
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1&1&1\\ &&1&1&1&1\\ &&&&1&1\\&&&&&&\ddots},
\ A^T=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1\\ &1&1\\ &1&1\\ &&1&1\\ &&1&1\\ &&&&\ddots}.
$$
We have $Ax=0$ for any $x\in\ell^2$ in the form of $(x_1,-x_1,x_2,-x_2,\ldots)^T$. Therefore the nullity of $A$ is infinite. However, $A^Tx=0$ has only the trivial solution.

**Failure of Both:** Take
$$
A=\pmatrix{
0 \\
0&\ddots\\ 
1&0\\ 
0&0&\ddots\\
&1&0\\
&0&0&\ddots }
$$

---

Now, why do these statements fail in infinite dimensions?  Recall that the reason this property holds in the finite dimensional case is due to the rank-nullity theorem.  In particular, for $A: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ (that is, $A$ is $m \times n$)
$$
\dim im(A) + \dim \ker(A) = n
$$
this result no longer applies in infinite dimensions, and we lose some consequences of this theorem.

For example, a fact that holds for a square matrix of finite size is that $A$ is injective (has a trivial null space) if and only if it is surjective.  This no longer applies in infinite dimensional spaces.  What we can still say, however, is that $A$ is injective if and only if $A^T$ is surjective (whether or not $A$ is square).  In our first example, then, we have an example of a map that is injective (has a trivial kernel) but is not surjective.  Consequenctly, $A^T$ turns out to be surjective but not injective.

Comment: @EricWofsey right, I forgot that $0$ is a finite number.  In any case, I suppose a modification of the first example would do.

Comment: (Example added)

Comment: You can regard infinite real matrices as unbounded linear operators $\ell^2\to \ell^2$ (as such, their domains are allowed to be different from $\ell^2$).

Comment: @studiosus sure, but getting used to changing the domain is a whole can of worms of its own, which I happily avoided.